# How to use "if" and "for" in VBA/Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I just want to know how to divide values on j3 to m3 using "if statement" and "for statement"

Sheet 1:

[image]

Comment: (a) You don't have to shout.  (b) If you have to submit this tomorrow, you have probably already been working on it for some time - please show your current code, and tell us what isn't working.

Comment: I'm not so conversant with Internet forum protocol either. Perhaps that's why I can't see how OP is shouting. I thought he is trying to be friendly.

Comment: @Variatus - Using all caps (i.e.in the title) is generally considered the internet equivalent of shouting.  (It also makes it harder to read, otherwise I wouldn't have worried about it.)

Comment: @Variatus: the perceived relationship between all-caps and shouting has been a thing since Usenet (25+ years ago) so we're at the point we need people to know this. This is essentially a request for free work anyway, so is off-topic.

Comment: @halfer Surely, the use of all caps in a worksheet doesn't tread on any sensitive toes. In the title, only VBA is all caps. I believe that is the correct name for VBA (not shouted). I accept that this question doesn't interest many other visitors, but I feel stackoverflow should be the place to go when one needs to know correct syntax.

Comment: @Variatus, I repaired the title - see the old shouty one [in the edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42941923/revisions). Yes, acronyms should be all-caps `:-)`.

Answer (score 1):

This should answer your question:-

```
Private Sub Example()
    ' 21 Mar 2017

    Dim Jclm As Long, Mclm As Long
    Dim Sclm As Long
    Dim Rend As Long
    Dim R As Long

    Jclm = Columns("J").Column
    Mclm = Columns("M").Column
    Sclm = Columns("S").Column                          ' write to column S

    With ActiveSheet
        Rend = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row    ' last row in column A
        For R = 2 To Rend
            If .Cells(R, Mclm).Value Then               ' .Value <> 0
                .Cells(R, Sclm).Value = .Cells(R, Mclm).Value / .Cells(R, Jclm).Value
            End If
        Next R
    End With
End Sub
```

Note that the formula `Columns("S").Column` will return a number specifying column S. You can let it specify another column by changing the letter "S" in it.

Comment: FWIW - Rather than setting a variable such as `Mclm`, the code `.Cells(R, Mclm)` could be replaced by `.Cells(R, "M")` (etc).  I tend to find it is easier to read using the letter instead of the number as the `Cells` column parameter.  (Obviously a numeric value will be easier to use if you are looping across several columns.)

Comment: Answering lazy questions with homework deadlines puts you at risk of downvotes, Variatus. It is very helpful of you, but we do not want to teach people that Stack Overflow is a source of free labour.